Why udelay does not change with CONFIG_HZ
I was writing a Linux driver, and I used the udelay function in my code. When I changed CONFIG_HZ from 100 to 1000 in the kernel configuration, my driver started experiencing issues. Eventually, I discovered that the timing of udelay() was incorrect.
// arch/arm/include/asm/delay.h
#define MAX_UDELAY_MS 2
 
#define udelay(n) \
(__builtin_constant_p(n) ? \
((n) > (MAX_UDELAY_MS * 1000) ? __bad_udelay() : \
__const_udelay((n) * ((2199023U*HZ)>>11))) : \
__udelay(n))

Initially, with udelay(10), the driver was working fine. However, after modifying CONFIG_HZ to 1000, the driver started malfunctioning and I had to change udelay(500) for it to work properly.
After examining the implementation code of udelay, I noticed that it uses HZ. So, why does udelay become inaccurate when CONFIG_HZ is modified?

What kernel version do you use? That implementation of udelay() was changed 12 years ago.

Are you building the driver with the same CONFIG_HZ value as the kernel? If not, then calling udelay with a built-in constant will use the wrong delay calculation. But calling udelay with a variable should use the correct delay calculation with an initial multiplication done at runtime that will increase the delay by a tiny amount. You shouldn't be changing kernel configuration options when building the driver.
